# Insert query with a column that is the total number of records from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that inserts data from another table, into an empty table (the table is cleared once a day, and new data is put in once a day). Currently it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO new 
       (website, 
       company, 
       address, 
       city, 
       state, 
       zip
SELECT f.website, 
       f.business, 
       f.[address line 1], 
       f.city, 
       f.state, 
       f.[zip code]
FROM   [finaltable] f;
```

What I would like to do, is include a row called "COUNT" on the insert, that would be total number of records of the table "finaltable".

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO new 
       (website, 
       company, 
       address, 
       city, 
       state, 
       zip,
       count
SELECT f.website, 
       f.business, 
       f.[address line 1], 
       f.city, 
       f.state, 
       f.[zip code],
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finaltable) AS COUNT
FROM   [finaltable] f;
```

But I have no idea how I would go about that, I'm not super familiar with subqueries like this.

Comment: Could be that your actual problem is just that you are trying to use the reserved word `COUNT` as your column name?

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Comment: Why would you want a table count on every record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use windowed `COUNT`:

```
INSERT INTO new 
       (website, 
       company, 
       address, 
       city, 
       state, 
       zip,
       [count])
SELECT f.website, 
       f.business, 
       f.[address line 1], 
       f.city, 
       f.state, 
       f.[zip code],
       [count] = COUNT(*) OVER()  -- count of rows returned by `SELECT`
FROM   [finaltable] f;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=58727c91ebbd40c654ca7b6202d8bf08)**

Comment: I gave this a spin in my dev enviornment, Its a 2016 SQL sever, but Im actually running the query through Access (it's easier for this situation) and I get the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[count] = COUNT(*) OVER()'". Is this perhaps just a weird quirk of Access?

Comment: @Natsu if you are running it through MS Access then you need to say that in your question as that is critical information - MS Access uses very different SQL to SQL Server.

Comment: I actually totally forgot I was running it through Access rather than a pss through until the moment it didnt work! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new 
       (website, 
       company, 
       address, 
       city, 
       state, 
       zip,
       Total)
SELECT f.website, 
       f.business, 
       f.[address line 1] , 
       f.city, 
       f.state, 
       f.[zip code],
       Total = COUNT(*) OVER() -- order by a specific field for ex:website
FROM   [finaltable] f;
```

or you can just use a plain old

```
INSERT INTO new 
           (website, 
           company, 
           address, 
           city, 
           state, 
           zip,
           Total)
    SELECT f.website, 
           f.business, 
           f.[address line 1] , 
           f.city, 
           f.state, 
           f.[zip code],
           count(*) as 'Total_Count'
    FROM   [finaltable] f;
```

But the `count(*)` or using a subquery version i.e.

```
select * , (select * from [finaltable]) 'Total_Count' from [finaltable]
```

gives the result of total rows / count to all the record lines of the table for that field i.e., if you have 1000 records , for all the 1000 records , you'll have the same value 1000 in the " COUNT/Total" field.